# Code for finding the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number

Tags: java, math

I am doing a project euler question as follows :

```
Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number.

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
```

Can anyone give me some tips for why my code below is incorrect please? My code currently outputs an answer of 570394440, which is wildly high. Can anyone give me some hints please? I have been staring at it for hours.

```
public class Euler3 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
          BigInteger bigInteger1 = new BigInteger ("7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450");
          int product=0;
          int product2=0;
          String values = bigInteger1.toString();
          for(int i = 0; i<values.length()-4; i++){
              product2 = ((((values.charAt(i) * values.charAt(i+1)) * values.charAt(i+2)) * values.charAt(i+3))* values.charAt(i+4));
              if(product2 > product){
                  product=product2;
              }
          }
          System.out.println(product);        
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need all those parentheses if you're just multiplying. `(2*3)*4` is just `2*3*4`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing that out - I had left them in from a pointless debug effort! :)

Comment: Not an error, but you are turning a String into a BigInteger, and then turning it back into a String again.  Why not cut out the middle-man?  `String values = "731671765 ... 63450";`

Comment: Also see  [Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6820764),

Comment: the answer should be `(40824, '99879')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

charAt() reports 48 for '0' and 49 for '1' etc. as it is the character values.

Subtract 48 from each and try again.

Comment: I'd use [Character.digit()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29) instead of mucking around with ASCII charts.

Comment: Ahh, I see, so the ASCII value for the string is returned? Whats the cleanest way of converting this please? :)

Comment: @SimonKiely: see Ryan Stewart's comment. It should be an answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels , thanks!      product2 = Character.digit(values.charAt(i), Integer.MAX_VALUE) * Character.digit(values.charAt(i+1), Integer.MAX_VALUE) * Character.digit(values.charAt(i+2), Integer.MAX_VALUE)  * Character.digit(values.charAt(i+3), Integer.MAX_VALUE) * Character.digit(values.charAt(i+4), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
returns a 0, however, and I cannot figure out why?

Comment: `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?!? wtf?  How about `10`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is meant by radix in this case! :)

Comment: Umn I have a hard time seeing how if `(48+a)*(48+b) > (48+c)*(48+d)` how `c * d > a * b` could be possible? Edit: Oh sorry, we want the product, so it'd obviously influence the result~

Comment: @SimonKiely: think of radix as the "base" of the number. Most numbers we deal with are base 10, hexadecimal numbers are base 16. You are making your number base impossibly huge, and I don't know what effect that might have.

Comment: @Voo, for sufficient large numbers the "+48" may be too big and wrap around to a small number.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen True enough, I was thinking more on the lines of a general mathematical statement, but yes considering overflows this throws the whole thing off.

Comment: @Voo, all optimizations (like fitting a number in a 32-bit integer for speed) have trade-offs.  You just need to know them so you don't have to do late night debugging.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the character code values, that's why the number is so high.

No need to store it as a BigInteger by the way, just use a string :-)