# the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product

Tags: java

this is my code for finding the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product.

can anyone tell me where did i do wrong?

```
for(int i = 0; i <= list.size()-13 ; i++){
    int result = list.get(i);
    for(int j = i +1; j <= i+12; j++){
        result = result * list.get(j);
                                     }
        if(result > this.max){
            this.max = result;
                             }
                                         }
```

UPDATE:
thanks for helping everyone, I should have used long instead of int. that's all.
problem solved. thanks again . :D

Comment: Can you be kind and explain " the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product." ?

Comment: @KickButtowski - It seems reasonably clear to me -- much clearer than several things I've seen here today.

Comment: @HotLicks sounds good, but can you explain what the op wants so I can learn?

Comment: The op wants to successively test each 13-digit sequence in the 1000 digit array, multiplying all 13 digits of the sequence together, then reporting the largest product found.

Comment: Yilin, you should tell us what's not working.  Is it crashing, getting the wrong value, what?

Comment: @KickButtowski  - Probably the same as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820764/find-the-greatest-product-of-five-consecutive-digits-in-the-1000-digit-number?rq=1) only with more digits.

Comment: Yilin, the basic scheme seems valid (if perhaps not optimal in terms of performance).  But there are several places where there could be a hidden off-by-one problem, and it's too late at night for me to think all those through.

Comment: thanks for helping everyone, the problem is I should have used long instead of int.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem is this:  `int`

A 32-bit `int` can store a number up to 2,147,483,647, but the possible product of 13 instances of the `9` digit is 2,541,865,828,329.

The `result` and `max` values need to be `long`, not `int`.

Comment: sorry baby, cann't vote up for you this time as I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but I thing this should work:

```
int const ADJ_NUMBERS= 13;
long maxVal = 0;
long currentVal;

for(int i = 0; i < list.size() - ADJ_NUMBERS; i++){
    currentVal = list.get(i);
    for(int j = 1; j < ADJ_NUMBERS; j++){
        currentVal *= list.get(i+j);
    }
    if(maxVal < currentVal){
        maxVal = currentVal;
    }
}
```

Result is in maxVal variable.

Regards.

edit: changed variable types to long, as pointed by Hot Licks at https://stackoverflow.com/a/28163140/4430913

Comment: Can you explain how/why your algorithm differs from Yilin's?